# Align center html page

Tags: html, css

Below is how our codes are currently design. With on some div and tables. The only problem now we want to make the whole page appear in center of the page irrespective of any resolution.Now the page appear towards left and I dont need to scroll horizontal either.

```
<body> 


<div id="main" 
<div id=logo>
<table width=1000>
<tr>
<td width=300>
<img src=lo.png  height="100" width="100" >
</td>
<td width=350 align=center>
    <label class=description for=element_1>Ent Page</label>  
</td>
<td width=350 align=right>
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=300>
<label class=description >Name:test1</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=300>
<label class=description >Ent Name:test1</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="nav"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="login.php">Main Page</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
<div align="left">
//menu here
</div>
<div id=dptions>
<table> 
<tr>
<td width=700 valign="top">


    <form action="db1.php" method="post" name="form1" id=form1 >
    <table id="mainDetails">
    <tr>

        </tr>

        </table>
        </form>
</td>
<td width=350 valign="top" align=left>
       <h2 class="form_desicription">Actives</h2>
       <table >
       <tr id="gridHeader">
               <td width="5%">
                No.
                </td> 
                <td width="25%">
                Active
                </td>               
                <td width="25%">
                Date Time Insert
                </td>               
                <td width="10%">
                Details
                </td>

            </tr>
            </table>
</td>

</tr>

</table>

</div>
<div id="nav"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="login.php">Main Page</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 

</div>

</body>
```

Below is my full .css file.

```
*

     { 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px; 
    } 
    body 
    { 
    background:#ffffff; 
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    font-size:small; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding:0; 

    } 

    #nav 
    { 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    height:19px; 
    width:1024px; 
    font-family:Calibri;
    }

    #nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    #nav li {
        float: left; position: relative;
    }

    #nav li a {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #371C1C;
    }

    #nav a:hover,
    #nav a:focus {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    h2.form_desicription
    {
        clear:left;
        font-family: Calibri;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #371C1C;

    }


    input.text
    {
        background:#fff url(../../../images/shadow.gif) repeat-x top;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
        border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
        border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:normal;
        padding:2px 0;
    }

    input.radio
    {
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:normal;
        padding:2px 0;
    }
    input.checkbox
    {
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:normal;
        padding:2px 0;
    }

    label.description
    {
        border:none;
        color:#222;
        display:block;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
        padding:0 0 1px;
    }

    label.list
    {
        border:none;
        color:#222; 
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
        padding:0 0 1px;
    }

    input.file
    {
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
        margin:0;
        padding:2px 0;
    }

    select.select
    {
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:normal;
        padding:2px 0;
    }

    textarea.textarea
    {   
        color:#333;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        margin:1px 0;
        padding:1px 0 0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
        border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
        border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
    }

    input.button_text
    {
        overflow:visible;
        padding:0 7px;
        width:auto;
    }

    .buttons input
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:700;
        margin-right:5px;
    }

    span.required
    {
        border:none;
        color:red;
        display:block;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
        padding:0 0 1px;
    }

    #gridHeader 
    { 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    font-size:12px;
    font-color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }

    #gridRow 
    { 
    background-color:#EFEEEE; 
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }
    #gridRow10 
    { 
    background-color:#EFEEEE; 
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }

    p.error
    {
        border:none;
        color:red;
        display:block;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
        padding:0 0 1px;
    }
    span.clearSearch
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;
    }
    span.statusOk
    {
        color: blue;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;

    }
    span.statusFailed
    {
        color:red;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:150%;

    }

    .show 
    {  
        display: block;  
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .hide 
    {  display: none;  
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: please create Fiddle or provide some of your CSS too!!!

Comment: As @AT-UID said, please provide more info and make some effort in your question.

Comment: @gnclmorais I have tried to make this design and align center the tables but does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving width to table give width to your "#main"

Use below code:

```
#main{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Refer this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/pdsPj/**

Hope this helps!

Comment: where to add this margin:0 auto ?

Comment: for a quick test I did this <style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0 auto
}
</style> but no difference its still align to left too.

Comment: I have added my full .css file too.

Comment: Make sure to define a width on the element you are trying to center.

Comment: Add this : #main{ margin:0 auto; width: 1000px;}

Comment: @AT-UID the problem on the content of the <div id=logo> gets centered the rest remain the same.

Comment: @AT-UID another thing both the <div id="nav"> stretch till the end of the page does not center either too.

Comment: If #main is not your outer most div, then give try giving the width and margin to Body like this, >  body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

Comment: @AT-UID yes my main is the most outer div with all the content suppose to be in it. I tried this now #nav 
{ 
background-color:#ccc; 
height:19px; 

font-family:Calibri;
margin:0 auto; 
width: 1000px;
} it works. So looks like I must set the width to a fix width and for for all my divs.

Comment: yes, you must set some Fixed width to your outer most Div or Body tag... But strange as per your code given in the question, its working find in the fiddle, but may be its clashing with some other CSS.. but overall the solution to your issue is to provide "margin" as "auto" for left and right, along with some defined width

Comment: @AT-UID I have tried just the div still cant. So no choice I got to put in the body this width: 1000px; then only all the below div works properly. But I got on file I include the Kool Tab as this $kts = new KoolTabs("kts");
 
//Step 3: Set properties for kooltabs
$kts->styleFolder = "KoolTabs/styles/silver";


$kts->addTab("root","Vbs","Vbs","vbs.php",$vsb);
$kts->addTab("root","Cms","cms","cms.php",$cms);



$kts->addTab("Vbs","Ast","Ast","ast.php",$ast); 
$kts->addTab("Vbs","NAst","NAst","nast.php",$nast); this one at it does not stay to the left of the page the location moves.